# Recommendations for a free GIS library supporting raster images

Tags: c++, dictionary, free, gis

I'm quite new to the whole field of GIS, and I'm about to make a small program that essentially overlays GPS tracks on a map together with some other annotations. I primarily need to allow scanned (thus raster) maps (although it would be nice to support proper map formats and something like OpenStreetmap in the long run).

My first exploratory program uses Qt's [graphics view framework](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/graphicsview.html) and overlays the GPS points by simply projecting them onto the tangent plane to the WGS84 ellipsoid at a calibration point. This gives half-decent accuracy, and actually looks good. But then I started wondering. To get the accuracy I need (i.e. remove the "half" in "half-decent"), I have to correct for the map projection. While the math is not a problem in itself, supporting many map projection feels like needless work. Even though a few projections would probably be enough, I started thinking about just using something like the [PROJ.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) library to do my projections. But then, why not take it all the way? Perhaps I might aswell use a full-blown map library such as [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) (edit: [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/) also looks very nice), which will probably pay off when I start to want even more fancy annotations or some other symptom of featuritis.

So, finally, to the question: What would *you* do? Would you use a full-blown map library? If so, which one? Again, it's important that it supports using (and zooming in and out with) raster maps and has pretty overlay features. Or would you just keep it simple, and go with Qt's own graphics view framework together with something like PROJ.4 to handle the map projections? I appreciate any feedback!

Some technicalities: I'm writing in C++ with a Qt-based GUI, so I'd prefer something that plays relatively nicely with those. Also, the library must be free software (as in FOSS), and at least decently cross-platform (GNU/Linux, Windows and Mac, at least).

**Edit:** OK, it seems I didn't do quite enough research before asking this question. Both [Quantum GIS](http://www.qgis.org/) and [Mapnik](http://mapnik.org/) seem very well suited for my purpose. The former especially so since it's based on Qt.

Comment: Oh and, I'm aware of the GIS Stack Exchange site, but its FAQ says it's for "...anyone interested in GIS *professionally*."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See GDAL www.gdal.org for a solid background library for raster formats and manipulation, and it incorporates PROJ.4 for transformations.

QGIS relies on GDAL for some data import, amongst other things.

Comment: Very interesting. Thank you. I'll leave the answer unaccepted until I make a decision or some other answer comes along.